# Coding error? Why is the treatment not showing as a significant effect with GLM and standard error is so high?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, interpretation, binomial-distribution, link-function

> I've been handed off some data to analyze and I'm looking for
> something simple and straightforward.  The main study question is
> testing the efficacy of 7 herbicides, with one untreated control. The
> 1 response variable of interest variable is mortality, which con be
> expressed a number of ways: % mortality, # of dead trees, average  %
> mortality, proportion of dead trees, etc. since I have the raw data of
> dead/alive for each of the 10 trees per treatment group at 6 sites.
> Since several treatments killed all the trees, the data is skewed and
> did not meet the assumptions of ANOVA, so I'm starting with the most
> simple model using the following, where the live/dead response live=0,
> dead=1. I'm new to this method of analysis but the output doesn't make
> sense to me with the data- am I coding something wrong or is there a
> better approach?

[image]

```
fm1<-glm(zeros~treatment, family=binomial(link="logit"), data=callerydata)
summary(fm1)

Call:
glm(formula = zeros ~ treatment, family = binomial(link = "logit"), 
    data = callerydata)

Deviance Residuals: 
     Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
-2.14597  -0.00005   0.00005   0.11480   1.55176  

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)  2.057e+01  5.607e+03   0.004    0.997
treatment2   6.423e-12  7.929e+03   0.000    1.000
treatment3   3.232e-09  7.929e+03   0.000    1.000
treatment4  -2.141e+01  5.607e+03  -0.004    0.997
treatment5  -1.918e+01  5.607e+03  -0.003    0.997
treatment6  -1.837e+01  5.607e+03  -0.003    0.997
treatment7  -4.113e+01  7.929e+03  -0.005    0.996
treatment8  -4.113e+01  7.929e+03  -0.005    0.996

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 105.850  on 79  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:  28.727  on 72  degrees of freedom
  (480 observations deleted due to missingness)
AIC: 44.727

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 19
```

Comment: (1) What happened to those 480 observations?  What were they intended to represent? (2) You aren't using the simplest model, which would be `zeros ~ 1`.  Fit that one, too, and compare the two models.  You will find yours is statistically significant.  (3) Simple and straightforward: this is a $2\times 8$ contingency table with a fixed margin. Do a Fisher's Exact Test. I get $p=3.959\times 10^{-14}.$

Comment: Which treatment is the control? What is the research question you want to answer with this model? Usually, you want to compare treatments to the control, which means you need to ensure that the control is the first factor level, which is represented by the model intercept.

Comment: the 480 observations are empty cells.  I'm not sure why R is recognizing them. @Roland I have since reordered to have the control as the intercept and can provide that output if that's helpful.  I'd really like to be able to be able to determine if there was a significant difference in mortality between the treatments.

Comment: Does that mean you want to do pairwise comparisons (post-hoc tests)? Look at the multcomp package.